# Using R INLA hyperparameter to.theta and from.theta functions

Tags: r, r-inla

`R-INLA` model hyperparameters have `to.theta` and `from.theta` functions that appear to be for converting between different parameterisations. It would be convenient to use those conversion functions but how does one do so?

## Example with `ar1`

From the `ar1` documentation (http://www.math.ntnu.no/inla/r-inla.org/doc/latent/ar1.pdf):

> The parameter rho is represented as theta_2 = log((1 + rho)/(1 - rho))

and further down under `hyper`, `theta2` we have `to.theta 'function(x) log((1+x)/(1-x))'`. It would be nice if we could use that to convert between rho and theta_2.

Let's try using an example

```
library(INLA)
# Example from ar1 documentation (http://www.math.ntnu.no/inla/r-inla.org/doc/latent/ar1.pdf)

#simulate data
n = 100
rho = 0.8
prec = 10
## note that the marginal precision would be
marg.prec = prec * (1-rho^2)
E=sample(c(5,4,10,12),size=n,replace=T)
eta = as.vector(arima.sim(list(order = c(1,0,0), ar = rho), n = n,sd=sqrt(1/prec)))
y=rpois(n,E*exp(eta))
data = list(y=y, z=1:n, E=E)
## fit the model
formula = y~f(z,model="ar1")
result = inla(formula,family="poisson", data = data, E=E)
```

That runs fine.
Can we use `to.theta` like this?

```
formula.to.theta = y~f(z,model="ar1", 
                       hyper = list(rho = list(initial = to.theta(0.25))))
result = inla(formula.to.theta,family="poisson", data = data, E=E)
# Error in to.theta(0.25) : could not find function "to.theta"
```

So we can't use it like that. Is there another way to specify `formula.to.theta` that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure the answer to your question is "no". The Documentation is saying, not that there are functions by those names in the package, but rather that the `hyper` hyperparameter element will have functions by those names with values as given in the documentation. There is no reason to think that pasting those names after `formula.` would result in a meaningful function. Here is how to examine the value of `from.theta` in the environment of a specific call to the `f`-function:

```
library(INLA)
eval( f(z, model = "ar1") )$hyper$theta3$from.theta
===== result ========
function (x) 
x
<environment: 0x7fdda6214040>
attr(,"inla.read.only")
[1] TRUE
```

The result from f( , "ar1") actually has three `theta`'s each with a to and from function. You may be trying to change the `hyper$thetax$param` value which does not have an `attr(,"inla.read.only")` value of `TRUE`.

It would probably be more informative for you to execute this:

```
eval( f(z, model = "ar1") )$hyper
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Using that, it looks like it is technically possible to get the desired result with: `formula.to.theta = y~f(z,model="ar1", hyper = list(rho = list(initial = eval( f(z, model = "ar1") )$hyper$theta2$to.theta(0.25))))`

Comment: Oh good. I misunderstood. I thought you wanted to modify one or more of the functions rather than extract the language element and pass an argument to one.